# Open a new tab in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I want to open a new tab and run this JavaScript in it:

```
document.body.scrollTop = document.getElementById("UserContainer").offsetTop-100
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the [chrome.tabs api](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) (probably chrome.tabs.create) to open the tab and then use a [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) to execute javascript within the context of the page.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it? Maybe the use of chrome.tabs.executeScript?

Comment: You could use the chrome tabs api to open and then inject into it with execute script yes